# Why is the PDF size of texstudio documents bigger than from overleaf?

Tags: texstudio, overleaf

When I am compiling my thesis, the document size from overleaf is about 930 KB, where the size of my texstudio document is 1.1 MB. Why is the a difference? I only use PDF files as figures. Does it mean any qualitative reasons?

Comment: Did you compile both files using the same compilation mechanisms (that is, PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX etc.)?

Comment: Yes, pdfLatex at both.

Comment: Perhaps there is a different amount of `\pdfcompresslevel` or `\pdfobjcompresslevel` set as default. You can set these yourself, but if you do not, the TeX system will apply its own defaults. My guess is that Overleaf sets more compression, for faster Internet transmission.

Comment: Ahh, make sense! Overleaf is much faster, too. Do you know what the standard level for texstudio is? And does it have a qualitative consequence to the figures?

Comment: i doubt they change it but you can use `\showthe\pdfcompresslevel` to see the values, But also what version of latex are you running, presumably `LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5` on overleaf

Comment: texstudio is just the editor you are using so has no effect here, what matters is what tex system you have installed

Comment: Yeah I use 2022 Version of PDFlatex on overleaf. Texstudio is installed on MacOS. Maybe this takes the difference. \pdfcompresslevel=9 is 1,1 MB, \pdfcompresslevel=0 is 2 MB.

Comment: as I say texstudio is not relevant here, what matters is the release of latex you are using.

Comment: I don’t know which I use, where can I see it?

Comment: Look at the first lines of any log file after a compilation. There you will find the relevant version numbers.

Comment: I get this one: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.12.14)

Comment: the latex version would be more relevant,  but anyway if you want to see what is different make a _small_ document that comes out different size, then put `\pdfcompresslevel=0 \pdfobjcompresslevel=0` at the top and compare the pdf from the two systems.

Comment: There is also the question of whether the fonts are loaded into the PDF or not.